# Reuse models in multiple Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built a web application. This application is very specialized for just one task.
In a new project, I'd like to reuse some database, model and controller I developed for the previous application. I don't need al the logic just some section.

I don't want to cut and past pieces of models and controllers.

Which is the best approach/strategy to accomplish this task ?

Do I have to create a plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reuse some of your models and controllers via [Rails Engines](http://rails-engines.org/). Check out this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines).